# List of dictionaries - how to format print output

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
lis = [{'score': 7, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 9, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}]
```

How can I format the output of a `print` function:

```
print(lis)
```

so I would get something  like:

```
[{7-0}, {2-0}, {9-0}, {2-0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comp will do:

```
['{{{0[score]}-{0[numrep]}}}'.format(d) for d in lst]
```

This outputs a list of strings, so *with* quotes:

```
['{7-0}', '{2-0}', '{9-0}', '{2-0}']
```

We can format that a little more:

```
'[{}]'.format(', '.join(['{{{0[score]}-{0[numrep]}}}'.format(d) for d in lst]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> print ['{{{0[score]}-{0[numrep]}}}'.format(d) for d in lst]
['{7-0}', '{2-0}', '{9-0}', '{2-0}']
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(['{{{0[score]}-{0[numrep]}}}'.format(d) for d in lst]))
[{7-0}, {2-0}, {9-0}, {2-0}]
```

Alternative methods of formatting the string to avoid the excessive `{{` and `}}` curl brace escaping:

- using old-style `%` formatting:

  ```
  '{%(score)s-%(numrep)s}' % d
  ```
- using a `string.Template()` object:

  ```
  from string import Template

  f = Template('{$score-$numrep}')

  f.substitute(d)
  ```

Further demos:

```
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(['{%(score)s-%(numrep)s}' % d for d in lst]))
[{7-0}, {2-0}, {9-0}, {2-0}]
>>> from string import Template
>>> f = Template('{$score-$numrep}')
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join([f.substitute(d) for d in lst]))
[{7-0}, {2-0}, {9-0}, {2-0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [ 
  {'score': 7, 'numrep': 0}, 
  {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}, 
  {'score': 9, 'numrep': 0}, 
  {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}
]

keys = ['score', 'numrep']
print ",".join([ '{ %d-%d }' % tuple(ll[k] for k in keys) for ll in l ])
```

*Output:*

```
{ 7-0 },{ 2-0 },{ 9-0 },{ 2-0 }
```

Comment: The order of `dict.values` is arbitrary.

Comment: Removed the -1. Still `'{%(score)s-%(numrep)s}'%ll` is better than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> lis = [{'score': 7, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 9, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 2, 'numrep': 0}] 
>>> ["{{{score}-{numrep}}}".format(**dic) for dic in lis]
['{7-0}', '{2-0}', '{9-0}', '{2-0}']
```

New-style formatting requires `{{}}` to escape a `{}`, so it's a bit less readable for this case. Another alternative is [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings), it allows `$` as place-holders for keys so the solution is much more readable in this case.:

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('{$score-$numrep}')
>>> [s.substitute(dic) for dic in lis]
['{7-0}', '{2-0}', '{9-0}', '{2-0}']
```

If instead list of strings you need a single string, then try this:

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('{$score-$numrep}')
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(s.substitute(dic) for dic in lis))
[{7-0}, {2-0}, {9-0}, {2-0}]
```